# maven assembly plugin excludes .gitignore

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

Maven assembly plugin exludes .gitignore files in the final zip package. How do I include .gitignore in the final output zip?
I tried include **/*, but didn't work.

My assembly file:

```
<id>assembly</id>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<formats>
    <format>zip</format>
</formats>
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.build.directory}/work</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>How*.html</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>`
```

Assembly plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <descriptors>
            <descriptor>assembly/config.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>build-archive</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Maybe it's because includeBaseDirectory is set to false.. Have you tried setting it to true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some research, I found that .gitignore and other source repository control files (.svn) are excluded in the final package. Maven does this by default. I had to explicitly set the flag - false to include .gitignore files.

As per maven documentation  - useDefaultExcludes -

> Whether standard exclusion patterns, such as those matching CVS and
>   Subversion metadata files, should be used when calculating the files
>   affected by this set. For backward compatibility, the default value is
>   true

.

Answer (score 0):

Three suggestions:

1- Try ***files*** element beside *fileSet* in your assembly file. It specifies which single files to include in the assembly. A file is specified by providing one or more of ***file*** subelements.

2- Set baseDirectory properly. for example

```
<baseDirectory>../</baseDirectory>
```

3- Or, set includeBaseDirectory to true

```
<includeBaseDirectory>true</includeBaseDirectory>
```

Comment: I tried all these and it didnt work. It would still ignore the .gitignore file

Answer (score 0):

Think of that, that Linux and MacOS don't show files in the Finder that start with a dot.

Use: Command + Shift + "."
to show hidden files.

Then I would also use :

```
<files>
    <file>
        <source> 'absolute or relative path' </source>
    </file>
</files>
```

If you think that still does not work and its still ignoring .gitignore
Try this workaround:

1. Rename your .gitignore file to _*gitignore*_

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GA5br.png)

If the **gitignore** is now in your zip as "my-project.jar" than its working.
If you set destination name to .gitignore and its just not showing up -> its hidden.

Use: Command + Shift + "."